# How to increment binary numbers where either an additional 1 is added or a 1 is removed

Tags: c#, binary, increment

So I was doing something for an assignment in C# to print out people's names in every combination.  If there were 5 people for example, I used a 5 digit binary number and just added 1 to it after each iteration.

00000 printed no names
00001 printed first name
00010 printed second name
00011 printed first and second name

... and so on.  Eventually, I could iterate through and print out every combination of names.

So, I was asked to just think about how could I do it only in one name was added or one name was subtracted.  If I understand this, I need to be able to systematically print out each combination but the next combination printed can only either have one more name than the last or one less name than the last.

I am looking for some help figuring out some logical approach to this.  I started here:

```
            00000   0 names
Add 1           00001   1 name
double, add 1   00011   2 names
subtract 1      00010   1 name
double, add 1   00101   2 names
subtract 1      00100   1 name
```

Here I don't see a logical pattern because if I double again I will miss out on 00111 for example so this was not right.  Anyway I am stuck at the moment.

I don't need any code, I can write that myself.  I just need maybe an idea on some better logic.  I am only choosing binary number approach here because that is what I was asked to think about.  Any ideas would be great.  Thank you

Comment: Does your class allow you to use bitwise operators?

Comment: We briefly talked about them a while back so I would assume yes

Comment: If you down vote could you please explain why?  I described my question, showed what I thought about and am not asking for the answer directly to writing the code.  I don't mind adjusting but say something.  I have researched.  I still am.  Sorry, if this question is not worth people's time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var found = new HashSet<string>();

IEnumerable<string> Mutate(string current)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < current.Length; i++)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(current);
        sb[i] = sb[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
        var r = sb.ToString();
        if (!found.Contains(r))
        {
            found.Add(r);
            yield return r;
            foreach (var r2 in Mutate(r))
            {
                yield return r2;
            }
        }
    }
}

var results = Mutate("00000").ToArray();
```

It outputs:

```
10000 
00000 
01000 
11000 
11100 
01100 
00100 
10100 
10110 
00110 
01110 
11110 
11010 
01010 
00010 
10010 
10011 
00011 
01011 
11011 
11111 
01111 
00111 
10111 
10101 
00101 
01101 
11101 
11001 
01001 
00001 
10001
```